# Creality 3D Ender-4, a "extruder kit" does not fit the frame

Tags: diy-3d-printer, printer-building, creality-ender-4

This is my first time building a 3D printer (a "[Creality Ender-4](https://www.3dprintersonlinestore.com/creality-ender4-3d-printer)").

Everything is going fine except the "extruder kit" part that does not have enough space to attach on the frame.  Should I drill it to have a longer hole so it can be attached to the frame? I just want another set of eyes to look at it to make sure I'm not crazy.

[image: Extruder - image#1]

[image: Extruder - image#2]
[image: Extruder - image#3]

Comment: It looks like the body of the stepper motor may not be quite square. Would you be able to install it rotated 90 degrees and get the clearance you need?

Comment: I submitted an edit that fixes the images

Comment: Try loosening all the screws that hold the motor/filament feeder to the bracket.  There may be enough slop to skooch it over a bit and get it to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, you're absolutely not crazy, I almost put the entire thing back in the box when I realized I'd have to void the warranty just to finish putting together my printer but I wound up boring out the holes a bit closer to the edges of the extruder and assembling it all the same, it works wonderfully now that I have it attached.

Comment: Yep, I ended up drilling the holes, and I've been printing successfully since then.

Answer (score 1):

From the photo on their website, it looks like you are orienting it correctly.

Here is a photo to confirm the orientation.
[image]

Note: I added this as an answer so I could share the photo

Answer (score 1):

Your request appears to be "another set of eyes" and I'll add to that by adding another photo:

[image: extruder mount]

If you compare the photo from the official store you can see the gap between the mounting screw and the body of the extruder assembly is obviously wider in the official photo. On the plus side, the extruder mount is not something that would be considered system critical, because you're using a Bowden tube design. Even a bit of misalignment would mean zero impact on the printed model quality.

Consider to contact the seller, including the photo from the store and your photo and ask for a correct mounting plate. You would likely be able to use the oversize hole mount until a replacement arrives. For such a small part, they should not charge you.

Comment: From this photo, it appears that the plate has slotted holes for the motor and extruder, and it looks like it is installed further to the right than on @koko's photos. Perhaps the position of the motor can be adjusted to make room?